# Plotting multiple addresses with distance to specific POI

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, api, bing-maps, mapquest

I'm not sure if this is the correct place for this question but here goes.

I am getting ready to move to a different city. Right now I have about 80 houses to choose from. One of my parameters for choosing a house is its distance from my work and from the church I plan on attending. What I would like to do is submit a list of addresses and get the distance/time between the house and my two POIs. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am a database developer/programmer by trade so I am not opposed to coding something if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to geocode the addresses, I would use [mapquest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/geocoding-service), then you have a list of points, so you could calculate the shortest distance between two points(house and POI):

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

or you could calculate the shortest path with google directions service:

```
function calcRoute(start,end) {
    var request = {
        origin:start, 
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var leg = result.routes[0].legs[0];
        console.log(leg.distance.value)
      }
    });
  }
```

remember that this calls to google maps API are asynchronous so you need to wait until the response arrives to call it again,(recursive maybe?)

And then just sort your results, with any criteria you want.